# Custom written Class not found when using aar library

Tags: android, android-library, aar

I am writing a library. When I include it as a module dependency inside the same project, the app works. If i generate aar file and include it libs folder, I am getting  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. What is stranger is that the class is written by me and is inside the library. It is not external library class.
The following error is thrown from inside the library.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.pacakge.ChatView$5
   at com.packge.ChatView.someFunction(ChatView.java:190)
```

at line 190, I am calling a static method of another class which is inside my library. 
Please help me understand why am I getting this error.

Comment: is `com.pacakge.ChatView` is intentionally using `pacakge` instead of `package`? just curious.

Comment: i have my own package, just replaced it that word just to hide the actual name. that was just a typo

Comment: Ohh, I see. The problem maybe related with access modifier. Is it a public or protected method? Just my guess.

Comment: It's public, regardless, it works when i add it as module dependency instead of aar library. Doesn't work when aar is used

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't about the class which i had written. 
In the same line, there was a reference to the class which was from volly library, and volley was not added as the dependency in my app. Apparently, all the dependencies in library's gradle have to be added in the app's gradle as well.